# Why mysql case condition not working correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following code

```
set @string:='11';

select CASE @string
           WHEN CAST(@a AS SIGNED)=11 THEN 'yes'
           ELSE 'no'
       END as filed;
```

I don't understand why it returns 'no'.

And also if I use `WHEN @string='11' THEN 'yes'` it also returns no.

Comment: What is `@a`???

Comment: There are *two* forms of a CASE expression: *simple* and *searched*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you were aiming for?

```
 set @string:='11'; 
 select CASE WHEN CAST(@string AS SIGNED)='11' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END as filed;
```

Can also be expressed as

```
set @string:='11';
select CASE CAST(@string AS SIGNED) when '11' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END as filed;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have not defined `@a`, so the value is `NULL`.

Hence, the `ELSE` clause is always going to be returned.

Then your second problem is that this does not work:

```
set @a = '11';
SELECT CASE @a
           WHEN CAST(@a AS SIGNED) = 11 THEN 'yes'
           ELSE 'no'
       END as filed;
```

This is because `CAST(@a AS SIGNED) = 11` is a boolean expression whose value is `0`, `1` or `NULL` and that is never `11`.

These do work:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(@a AS SIGNED) = 11 THEN 'yes'
           ELSE 'no'
       END as filed;


SELECT CASE @a WHEN 11 THEN 'yes'
           ELSE 'no'
       END as filed;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set @string:='11';

select CASE WHEN CAST(@string AS SIGNED) = 11 THEN 'yes'
            ELSE 'no'
       END as filed;
```

#### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/106583)